# MySQL - SUM() old entries

Tags: mysql

I've a table with lots of entries consisting of dates and a number.

For instance:

```
07.02.2016 - 12
06.02.2016 - 48
05.02.2015 - 24
```

...and so on.

Now I need to sum all of the values older than 2 months. For instance the 3rd entry (`05.02.2015`) will be added to the second (`06.02.2016`) and the second one should get the value 72 and the 3rd one should be deleted.

I'd like to know if there is some way to do this in mysql only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a ROLLING sum over a period of time in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213633/create-a-rolling-sum-over-a-period-of-time-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the code for you, I'd like to merely give you some hints:

- Identify which rows are older than 2 month and sum them up.

  ```
  select sum(number) from table where date > curdate() + interval 2 months
  ```

  or sth. similar will do.
- Select the max. date of the entries that are smaller or equal to "now+2months".
- Update that row with the value from step 1.
- Delete the rows from step 1.

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for details on date functions in MySQL.

This can be done in 2 statements (one for steps 1-3, one for the deletion).