# How to get subsequent total of column in next row using mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-query-store

I am creating one SQL query for stock entry. In the last column, I need the total of the previous stock purchase.

```
S No    Product Code    Qty     Qty Total
1       PO1             5       5  
2       PO1             12      17
3       PO1             10      27
4       PO1              8      35
5       PO1              9      44
6       PO1             16      60
```

In every row of the last column, I am adding all the previous quantity for example S no. 1 quantity is 5. In S No. 2 I am adding quantity 5 and 12=17. S No 3 I am adding 5 + 12+10=27 and Soo on.

I am sorry if it is a duplicate question. I search google and StackOverflow but didn't get the answer. I am new to MySQL
I have added query below. I am new to SQL, any help appreciated,

Thanks in Advance.

```
CREATE TABLE `stock_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `stock_table` (`ID`, `product_code`, `qty`) VALUES
(1, 'PO1', 5),
(2, 'PO1', 12),
(3, 'PO1', 10),
(4, 'PO1', 8),
(5, 'PO1', 9),
(6, 'PO1', 16);
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Do `SELECT Version();` and report the results of this query into the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate a running total in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql)

Comment: More answers available at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2563918/2469308 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19213633/2469308 and

Comment: I used select version: output is 10.1.34-MariaDB, I am using xamp

Answer (score 1):

You need a running sum. If you are using MySQL v 8.0, You can use SUM window function -

```
SELECT `ID`,
       `product_code`,
       `qty`,
       SUM(`qty`) OVER (PARTITION BY `product_code` ORDER BY `ID`)  Qty_Total
FROM `stock_table`;
```

<kbd>[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46422d783948c10adb581a141254e90e)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, Bro, It is working in MySQL 8, but I am using xamp and in it, it is not working on that.. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY `product_code` ORDER BY `ID`)
FROM `stock_table` LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

Comment: first it is saying unexpected token  to Qty_Total

Comment: It seems you are using MariaDB which doesn't support window function. Try Barbaros Özhan's answer.

Comment: when I removed the Qty_Total ,it is show ing above error #1064

Comment: @Gagandeep indeed, both answers are useful(+1), but windows analytic functions requires version 8+ as Ankit already mentioned.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Bro, His answer is awesome, still looking for more better option

Comment: I am pretty sure, You can never found a better answer than him.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery to sum up the desired column as the row proceeds by increasing `ID` value :

```
select t.*,
       ( select sum(`qty`) from `stock_table` where `ID` <= t.`ID` ) as "Qty Total"
  from `stock_table` t
 order by t.`ID`;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=397f9f4d9684704fe57694ad4053bb84)</kbd>

P.S. : as the sample data has unique `product_code` value, I didn't need to include the part related to `product_code` column's matching within the subquery,  if it's the case, then consider converting your derived column to :

```
( select sum(`qty`) 
    from `stock_table` 
   where `ID` <= t.`ID` 
     and `product_code` = t.`product_code` ) as "Qty Total"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of MariaDB does not support window functions.  That leaves you with two options.  One is a correlated subquery; the second is variables.

The first is easier to implement:

```
select st.*,
       (select sum(st2.qty)
        from stock_table st2
        where st2.product_code = st.product_code and
              st2.id <= st.id
       ) as running_qty
from stock_table st;
```

For performance, you want an index on `stock_table(product_code, id, qty)`.